# Calculate axis rotation for object to look at 3D Point

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

I want to program an industrial robot, so that the flange (the „head“ of the robot) is constantly looking at specified points in 3D world space.

- The real world position a(x,y,z) of the robot is set and lies on the basis of the coordinate system.
- The coordinate system of the robot is as follows: x is to the right, y is going "into the screen" and z is up. This is also shown in image [Start Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4mX6.jpg).
- A is rotation about Z, B is rotation about Y and C is rotation about X.
- In its default position with A=B=C=0 the flange is facing towards (0,0,1).
- List The Position b(x,y,z) is also set.
- The robot rotates in the following order: A > B > C

After rotating, the flange should look in the direction of the point b ([Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7taLh.jpg)).

I already found these calculations:

`rotx = Math.atan2( y, z )
 roty = Math.atan2( x * Math.cos(rotx), z )
 rotz = Math.atan2( Math.cos(rotx), Math.sin(rotx) * Math.sin(roty) )`

in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251828/calculate-rotations-to-look-at-a-3d-point) topic, which covers the same topic. I tried to fit the assumptions from the coordinate system in that topic to mine, switching y and z axis and changing the signs, but I ended up with the wrong results for some test coordinates.

Therefore, I'm looking for formulas for the rotations A,B and C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to answer this, I'll have to make some assumptions about the robot that you did not make clear in your post. I assume that the $A$ rotation moves the axes about which the $B$ and $C$ rotations occur, and the $B$ rotation moves the axis about which the $C$ rotation occurs. The problem with these assumptions is that the $A$ and $B$ rotations are sufficient to point in any direction. Even if the flange must be aligned in more than one dimension, this is accomplished by a third rotation about the $Z$ axis again, not a rotation about the $X$ axis. So if these assumptions are incorrect, please explain how the rotations actually work.

With the assumptions above, we can easily find the $A$ and $B$ rotations needed to point at $b$. The $A$ rotation will swing the $X$ axis around so that it aligns with $b$. I.e., $b$ will lie in the new $XZ$ plane. The $B$ rotation then lowers the $Z$ axis elevation down to the elevation of $b$. It may be simpler to view it from body coordinates - the coordinate system tied to the flange: then we don't view it as the axes changing direction, but rather, as moving $b$ around in the body coordinates.

First we determine the rotation angle $A$. If $b = (x, y, z)$, then $A$ will be the angle between the projection of $b$ into the $XY$ plane and the $X$ axis. The projection is $(x, y, 0)$, and the angle is given by `A = atan2(x, y)`. This rotation changes the body coordinates of $b$ to $(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, 0, z)$.

The $B$ rotation is then the angle between the positive $Z$ axis and this new direction for $b$, which given by `B = atan(z, sqrt(x^2 + y^2))`.